# JQuery event on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
```

Then this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() { console.log('foo'); });
```

Anytime I click on the button doesn't log "foo". Why?

---

**Solution:** I just had to take care about the event propagation.

Comment: check for errors in console

Comment: Don't have any error. It actually works in any other case but not in my project...

Comment: Can you explain what your solution was?   It looks like it was solved by something that was not included in the original question, but could be of use to someone else with a similar issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah just give me some time, I'll give a better explanation as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() { console.log('foo'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click Me</button>
```

instead, as it will register event on the document level and it should work.

Comment: I don't understand, what's different between your code and mine? By the way, the problem was my way to manage the event propagation as I said in right below my question.

Comment: As I figured out from my experience, attaching an event to a document usually means that you will have a little bit more comfort in terms of speed (not that noticable) and it will sure find your element if it exists and it doesn't care if it's loaded later or with ajax, where with attaching an event to a 'body' means that the browser has to find a body first, then the element, and can sometimes fail to do so.